# Real Analysis. Derivative Question Help

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The question is:

Let $I$ be an interval. Prove that if $f$ is differentiable on $I$ and if the derivative $f'$ is bounded on $I$, then $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition on $I$.

My attempt:

As $f'$ is bounded on $I$, for any $x,y\in I$, $\vert{\lim\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}}\vert\leq K$ for some constant $K$. Now, I know that I have to get the Lipschitz condition: $\vert{f(x)-f(y)}\vert\leq K\vert{x-y}\vert$. But what do I do about the limit? Is this a wrong approach? Could somebody help me out please?

Comment: Do you remember the mean value theorem?

Comment: You do not need the limit. The idea of limit-taking is already present in the $\forall x,y \in I$ hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $M$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in I$. Let $x,y\in I$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $c\in (x,y)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. Because $I$ is an interval, $c\in I$, so $|f'(c)|\leq M$. The result now follows easily.

Comment: Obviously, but the question is labeled "real analysis", so I assumed it would be $f: I\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$f(x+h)-f(x)
=\int_0^1 f'(x+th)hdt
$$

Now use the triangle inequality.